# How do i use a LINQ Results set to get a group by Count and show it with Viewdata on mvc razor page

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.0, viewdata, razor-pages

I am trying to create a couple of bootstrap cards that show the count of the number of tickets at a status. However i am struggling to get the data from the results query into a viewdata.  I have other drop downs ect that work via similar methods (viewbags).

The page is just showing a blank for the variable, like it does not exist.

```
public void CountofType(IQueryable<Tickets> _Tickets)
    {

        var CountType = _Tickets
            .GroupBy(T => new { T.Type })
                .Select(group => new 
                {
                    Text = group.First().Type,
                    //Value = group.First().Type.Count()
                    Value = group.Count()
                }
                );
        ViewBag.CountType = CountType;

        ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(T => T.Text == "OPEN" );

        ViewData["CountTypeCLOSED"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(X => X.Text == "CLOSED");

        ViewData["CountTypeOTHER"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(Y => Y.Text != "OPEN"
                                                                     || Y.Text != "CLOSED");

    }`
```

The HTML card will look something like this:

```
 <div class="card-deck">

            <div class="card text-white mb-3 bg-primary" style="max-width: 18rem; max-height: 7rem;>
                <a href=@Url.Action("index", new { Statuses = "OPEN" }) class="btn btn-fix text-left">
                    <div>
                        <h1 class="card-title text-white text-center">@ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"] </h1>
<h5 class="card-title text-white text-center">Open Tickets</h5>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine, for the most part. However, the way you're accessing the `ViewData` member in your view is problematic. First, the value is an anonymous object, which you can't simply dump to the page as you're doing. You would need to access one of the members of that object. For example, `@ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"].Text`. However, that will actually fail, because `ViewData` the value is not typed, and `object` doesn't have a `Text` property. You would first need to cast it as `dynamic`: `@(ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"] as dynamic).Text`.

That said, based on what you're doing here, all of that is kind of unnecessary. You *know* what particular type you're accessing, so all you need is the count. Therefore, you can change your action code to:

```
 ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(T => T.Text == "OPEN")?.Value ?? 0;
```

Then, in your view, you wouldn't need to change anything, because now `ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"]` is actually just your ticket count alone.

Comment: Thank you very much :), this put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much :), this put me on the right track.

I changed the function a so there is less processing overhead. but as i am new at C# i am unsure which is the best method.

```
ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"] = CountType.Count(T => T.Text == "OPEN");
```

or

```
ViewData["CountTypeCLOSED"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(T => T.Text != "OPEN")?.Value ?? 0;
```

The new procedure:

```
public void CountofStatus(IQueryable<Tickets> _Tickets)
    {
        var CountType = _Tickets
                .Select(group => new
                {
                    Text = group.Status,
                    Value = group.Status.Count()
                }
                );

        ViewData["CountTypeOPEN"] = CountType.Count(T => T.Text == "OPEN");
        //ViewData["CountTypeCLOSED"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(T => T.Text != "OPEN")?.Value ?? 0;
        ViewData["CountTypeCLOSED"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(T => T.Text != "CLOSED")?.Value ?? 0;
        ViewData["CountTypeSCHEDULED"] = CountType.FirstOrDefault(Y => Y.Text == "SCHEDULED")?.Value ?? 0;

    }
```

Comment: my next idea is to create this into a dynamic status count using a @foreach() that will display all available status's within the results set.